# useEffect goes to cyclic dependency with Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

Tryed to render component using useEffect with "product" dependency but it goes cyclic dependency.

Tryed to use prev state but it doesn't help.

React don't gives any error, but useEffect send request every second.
Component:

```
export const ProductPage = (props: any) => {
    const { product, isLoading, error } = useTypedSelector(state => state.Product)
    const dispatch = useTypedDispatch()
    const { id } = useParams()
    
    const prevProd = usePrevious(product)

    useEffect(() => { 
        if (prevProd !== product){dispatch(fetchProduct(Number(id)))}
    }, [product])
    return (
            <div>
                <div>{product.name}</div>
                <div>{product.id}</div>
                <div>{product.price}</div>
            </div>
    )
}
```

Async Thunk:

```
export const fetchProduct = createAsyncThunk(
    'product/fetch',
    async (id: number, thunkApi) => {
        try {
            const response = await productService.fetch(id)
            return response.data
        } catch (error: any) {
            return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error.message)
        }
    }
)
```

Slice:

```
export const ProductSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'product',
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: {
        [fetchProduct.fulfilled.type]: (state, action: PayloadAction<IProductData>) => {
            state.error = ''
            state.isLoading = false
            state.product = action.payload
        },

        [fetchProduct.pending.type]: (state) => {
            state.isLoading = true
        },

        [fetchProduct.rejected.type]: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
            state.isLoading = false
            state.error = action.payload
        },
    }
})
```

Explain please, why this problem occured and how resolve this?

Comment: Please show entire error message

Comment: No error. Every second useEffect send request

Comment: You are changing the product in the useEffect. You also run useEffect every time you change the product. Why do run this `useEffect` when `product` changes?

Comment: Because in this component I have header component that changes "product". When go to this component from another, all ok. But I don't understand why product changes if I change only "isLoading" in state

Comment: You change the product as well `state.product = action.payload`

Comment: Yes, and when expect only 1 request, redux dev tools shows cycle of actions product/fetch/pending and product/fetch/fulfilled

Comment: But every time product is changed you run the function that changes the product. That's obvious infinite loop.

Comment: This is reason why added checking prev state and present state

Comment: But the `product` is different every time. This check does nothing

Comment: Ok. I resolve this problem using action cretor in other component that changes product